# Bytes Concatenation problem with None in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation, byte

```
total = None

for i in range(2):

        item_1 = b'\x01'

        item_2 = b'\x02'

        item_3 = b'\x03'
       
        # concatenation
        combined = item_1 + item_2 + item_3 # which makes b'\x01\x02\03'
        
        total = total + combined            # to make b'\x01\x02\03\x01\x02\03'
```

In the above, I get a error because I cannot concatenate None with Bytes. One way I am thinking is to give some value(let's say `b'\x00'`) to total and remove in the total later, but not sure how to do it. Can someone please tell a away to achieve the above

Comment: use `total= b''` instead of None

Comment: @TomášŠturm , I will try that. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Filter on possible None arguments. filter(None, args) will return an iteratable that holds all values with bool(value) == True

```
def combine_bytes(*args):
return b''.join(filter(None, args))
```

You can then call:

```
combine_bytes(b'\x01', None, b'\x02', b'\x03', False)
```